Region Growing - which Version Python and Open3d could work together?
i became always the same error after applying region growing to my 3d pointcloud
i tried all the versions of open3d but it's also not working. with which version should i dowmload? for python and open3d?
here is the code:
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file_path = (file_path)

pcd.estimate_normals(search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=0.05, max_nn=30))

distance_threshold = 0.05  # Distance threshold (5 cm)
angle_threshold = np.deg2rad(30)  # Angle threshold (30 degrees)
min_cluster_size = 100  # Minimum cluster size to consider a region valid
labels = np.zeros(len(pcd.points), dtype=np.int32)
next_label = 1
queue = []

def grow_region(seed_index):
    queue.append(seed_index)
    labels[seed_index] = next_label

    while queue:
        current_index = queue.pop(0)
        current_point = pcd.points[current_index]
        current_normal = pcd.normals[current_index]

        [k, idx, dist] = pcd.search_radius_vector_3d(current_point, distance_threshold)

        for neighbor_index in idx:
            if labels[neighbor_index] == 0:  # Point not labeled yet
                neighbor_normal = pcd.normals[neighbor_index]

                # Calculate the angle between the normals
                dot_product = np.dot(current_normal, neighbor_normal)
                angle = np.arccos(dot_product)

                # Check if the angle is within the angle threshold
                if angle <= angle_threshold:
                    # Label the point and add it to the queue
                    labels[neighbor_index] = next_label
                    queue.append(neighbor_index)

for i in range(len(pcd.points)):
    if labels[i] == 0:  # Unlabeled point
        grow_region(i)
        next_label += 1  # Increment the label index

colors = plt.get_cmap("tab20")(np.linspace(0, 1, next_label))
colors = colors[labels]

pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors)

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])

and here is the Error

AttributeError: 'open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry.PointCloud' object has no attribute 'search_radius_vector_3d'


